# To grep for a word before matching pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the below output. I want to extract the number before the text. Like for example, I grep for `TrainIdentifyBusinessError` and I want `1612` to be displayed. 
I grep for `TrainIdentifyTechnicalError` and I want `3` to be displayed.

```
1612 TrainIdentifyBusinessError 252 TrainIdentifySuccess 3 TrainIdentifyTechnicalError
```

Comment: Are these on diferent lines?

Comment: You mean "below _input_", right?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sed` instead... for example

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*( |^)([0-9]+) TrainIdentifyBusinessError.*/\2/p' file
1612
```

or

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*( |^)([0-9]+) TrainIdentifySuccess.*/\2/p'
252
```

or

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*( |^)([0-9]+) TrainIdentifyTechnicalError.*/\2/p'
3
```

- `-n` don't print anything until we ask for it
- `-r` use ERE
- `.*` any number of any chars on the line
- `( |^)` space or start of line
- `([0-9]+)` one or more digits and `(save this)`
- `\2` back reference to the second `(saved pattern)`
- `p` print the edited line

Afterthought... if you need to do this regularly you could make a shell function (add to your shell's `~/.*rc` file, for example, `~/.bashrc` if you use bash), for example:

```
getnum() { sed -nr 's/.*( |^)([0-9]+) TrainIdentify'"$1"'.*/\2/p' "$2" ; }
```

Usage example (specify the field and the filename on the command line - if the file is always the same file, you could put the full path to it inside the function instead of `"$2"`):

```
$ getnum BusinessError file
1612
$ getnum TechnicalError file
3
$ getnum Success file
252
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, except the number has a decimal point in it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using the Perl extension for `grep` (the `-P` flag).
To get `3` from `TrainIdentifyTechnicalError`:

```
$ echo "1612 TrainIdentifyBusinessError 252 TrainIdentifySuccess 23 TrainIdentifyTechnicalError" | grep -Po "[[:digit:]]+ *(?=TrainIdentifyTechnicalError)"
23
```

To get `1612` from `TrainIdentifyBusinessError`

```
$ echo "1612 TrainIdentifyBusinessError 252 TrainIdentifySuccess 23 TrainIdentifyTechnicalError" | grep -Po "[[:digit:]]+ *(?=TrainIdentifyBusinessError)"
1612
```

Comment: With slight modification you can get `DP-1-1` refresh rate. For example: `xrandr | sed -n '/^DP-1-1/,/^[^ ]/p' | grep -Po '[[:digit:].]+ *(?=\*+)'` returns: `53.98`.